# How can I override FOSUserBundle form using my own fields(Symfony 3)?

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

My RegistrationType class code:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

/**
 * Форма регистрации пользователя
 */
class RegistrationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('adress');
        $builder->add('mobileNumber');
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType';
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'app_user_registration';
    }

}
```

It give me standart form with added fields "adress" and "mobileNumber".

Where can I choose which standart fields I want to use?

What should I change to get only "adress" and "mobileNumber" fields?
Thank you!

Comment: Why would you like to only have these fields in the registration form ? Won't you let the user chose his login/password ?

Comment: I want register users by mobile phone, not by password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my example of code, which I write with your advices. I hope it helps someone) Thanks to all!

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

/**
 * Форма регистрации пользователя
 */
class RegistrationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('address', null, [
            'label' => 'Адрес дома',
            'attr'=> [
                'placeholder' => 'placeholder-text'
                ]
            ]);
        $builder->add('mobileNumber', null, [
            'label' => 'Мобильный телефон',
            'attr'=> [
                'placeholder' => '+7 (999) 123-45-67'
                ]
        ]);
        $builder->add('username', null, [
            'label' => 'ФИО',
            'attr'=> [
                'placeholder' => 'Иванов Иван Иванович'
                ]
        ]);


        $builder->remove('email');
        $builder->remove('plainPassword');
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
//        return 'fos_user_registration';
        return 'FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->getBlockPrefix();
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'app_user_registration';
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your question is "How to remove fields from a form" then:

Solution 1:

You can remove any field from a form with that builder method

```
$builder->remove('your_field_name')
```

Maybe you should also override the FOSUser controller to fill the mandatory fields of your user entity. It depends how you modify your user entity.

Solution 2:
Using Form Options

Take a look here https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/question-answer-day/remove-form-field

Comment: Unfortunatly, I have less than 15 reputation, so I can't make publicity yet.

Comment: I have also had that reputation problem. So if you wish you can come back and vote when your repuation will be high enough. 
Have a good Symfony day :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is a very good article on this topic:

**[Overriding Default FOSUserBundle Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_forms.html)**

Have you defined your forma as a service via `form.type` tag? Have you told FOS about your form type in `services.yml` (via `fos_user.registration.form` key)?

Comment: Of course, I edit config.yml and services.yml according to recommendations in [official Documentation Symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html).